# Xfinium remove the border in the specific table cell

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin

I want to remove borders in the specific table cells, so I set borders width to 0, like in the code below

`cell.Borders = new PdfFlowContentBorders(new PdfPen(PdfRgbColor.Black, 0));`

I expect that those borders will disappear, but instead I got thin black border.
[image: result]

And here is what I get when set the border color to white

[image: result]

Comment: Drawing a line with width 0 in PDFs usually means drawing a line as thin as possible while still being visible. For no line you probably should try and not set a border at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a border to null if you do not want that border to be drawn.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops XFINIUM.PDF library.